# Kitchen Sink Spray Gun Inquiry

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, kitchen-sink

I have had a kitchen spray gun in the past and now I am trying to install one again but am having difficulty. I stopped for sometime and used a soap dispenser in its place. I also replaced the kitchen faucet itself some time ago and left the house/country for a few years.

At any rate, now I don't see the push and plug to push the end of the spray gun nozzle into. Do I need to purchase a push and plug piece (if that exists) or will I have to get an entire new faucet in order to use the spray gun attachment?

Thanks. 
Fee

Comment: If you're referring to the sleeve through which the hose passes, and the base trim, they're available at hardware stores.

Answer (score 1):

If the faucet set currently installed in the sink is sprayer compatible, it should have a third tube coming out of the faucet body/mixing valve. Also note, unless there is a sprayer shut off valve or a fitting that automatically stops any flow to the sprayer when the mating plug is not connected, it would shoot a hard stream of water out anytime the water was turned on. My guess is that there is no sprayer feed in the set you have installed now.  If you put a pic of the bottom of the set from under the sink, we would know for sure.